# yii2. Проблема с доступом к action в backend

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. Когда я создаю новый action , и перехожу на него ,то backend его не видит, хотя actionLogout, actionLogin,actionIndex - работают, но мои - нет.

Код в файле backend/config/main.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой .htacces файл в главной директории

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл .htacces в директории backend/web/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

action во frontend работают отлично. Эта проблема только с actions в backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ заключался в том, что в контроллере нужно указать доступ для action в методе
`public function behaviors()`

```
[
    'actions' => ['youAction', 'page'],
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => your role,
],
```